# I have an unexpected infinite loop using `for` in C

Tags: c, infinite-loop

I'm working on a simple (simple minded?) implementation of AES for learning purposes. I have made a small utility for generating the SBox table, but am having an odd infinite loop, which keeps spitting out the table ad infinitum. Below is the code in C that I'm trying to use. I just can't seem to get it under control! I expected this to spit out 256 SBox values; it's the same basic way that I (successfully) generated the log and anti-log tables.
The actual `sbox()` function is implemented in an external file and is prototyped in the included header file. Note that I have successfully tested `sbox()` to ensure that it returns the correct value for any given input; ok up to that point. Note that I am using unsigned char for in index variable type, as `sbox()` expects that type.
I know I'm missing something simple, and will be embarrassed, but grateful once someone has shown me the error of my ways. ;-) Thanks in advance!

```
//mk_sbox.c
//output the sbox table

#include "gfmath.h" 

int main() {
    
    uchar i,e;

    //display table
    printf("sbox table:\n");
    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
        e=sbox(i);
        printf("%hhu",e);
        printf("%c",',');
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried using `while` instead of `for`, but I get the same result. In case it matters here is the version of GCC:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
```

I'm working in a GitHub Codespace.

Comment: An uchar has a range of 0 to 255, so it will always be less than 256 and the for loop will never end.

Comment: Why `printf("%c",',')` and not `printf(",")`?

Comment: Or just `putchar(',')`

Comment: Tip: add `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to your compiler options and it will tell the answer to this and many other mysteries.

Comment: @Jonathan Adams, What is the return type from `sbox()`?

Comment: From my header file: extern uchar sbox(uchar n);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of `unsigned char` type is `[0, 255]`, when `i` is `255`, incrementing `i` (`i++`) result in its value wrap around and its value becomes `0`. In next iteration the loop condition `i < 256` result in `true` and loop continues.

To solve this, either change the type of `i` to `unsigned int` *(as suggested in other post)* or use `do..while` loop, like this:

```
    unsigned char i = 0;
    do {
        // loop body
    } while (i++ < 255);
```

Additional -

You can combine these two statements

```
        printf("%hhu",e);
        printf("%c",',');
```

in one

```
        printf("%hhu,",e);
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked beautifully! I knew I had overlooked something basic. Thanks also for the printf() tip, and thanks to the others who took the time to answer. I also see the sense of a do...while in a case like this.

Answer (score 4):

Change `i` to `unsigned int`. `uchar` has the range `0`..`255` so it will never reach `256`.